# question with java code for else statement. i keep getting error on line 17

Tags: java, if-statement

Multiple markers at this line

- The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
- Syntax error, insert `AssignmentOperator Expression` to complete 
   Assignment
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int n;
        int numberofInputs;
        int Sum;     

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            while ((n = input.nextInt()) !=0) {
                if(n>0) {
                    Sum +=n;
                    numberofInputs++;
                }
                else (n<0) {         //line 17 errors
                    System.out.print("error");
                }

            }
            //avg = sum/n
        System.out.print(Sum/numberofInputs); 
    }
}
```

Comment: the answers below failed to catch that `numberofInputs` and `sum` also both need to be initialized to a value.....also don't capitalize variables

Answer (score 3):

you should not put condition on else

```
else (n<0)
```

just use

```
if (n>0) {
…
} else {
…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't use a condition with else**. Try **removing the condition** or **using else if**. The correct and controlled code would be:

```
   public static void main(String [] args) {
        int n;
        int numberofInputs;
        int Sum;     

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            while ((n = input.nextInt()) !=0) {
                if(n>0) {
                    Sum +=n;
                    numberofInputs++;
                }
                else if (n<0) {         //Use 'else if' not 'else'
                    System.out.print("error");
                }

            }
            //avg = sum/n
        System.out.print(Sum/numberofInputs); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java an extra if condition sintax is

...

```
else if(n > 0)
```

...

so you need to add it